# Elixir Map reduce

Tags: elixir

I have a list of maps:

```
[%{~D[2019-02-11] => 7},
 %{~D[2019-02-12] => 1},
 %{~D[2019-02-15] => 1}]
```

I'm trying to turn it into one big map with:

```
my_map
|> Enum.map_reduce(%{}, fn x, acc ->
   Map.merge(x, acc)
end )
```

but alas, it isn't quite right. What's the right way to do this?

Comment: map_reduce should returns a tuple where the first element is the mapped enumerable and the second one is the final accumulator.
https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#map_reduce/3.
`my_map
|> Enum.map_reduce(%{}, fn x, acc -> {x, Map.merge(x, acc)} end )`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don’t need [`Enum.map_reduce/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#map_reduce/3) at all, use plain old good [`Enum.reduce/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#reduce/2):

```rb
[%{~D[2019-02-11] => 7},
 %{~D[2019-02-12] => 1},
 %{~D[2019-02-15] => 1}]
|> Enum.reduce(&Map.merge/2)
#⇒ %{~D[2019-02-11] => 7,
#    ~D[2019-02-12] => 1,
#    ~D[2019-02-15] => 1}
```

---

Also, for the case there are no duplicated keys

```elixir
for m <- list, {k, v} <- m, into: %{}, do: {k, v}
#⇒ %{~D[2019-02-11] => 7, ~D[2019-02-12] => 1, ~D[2019-02-15] => 1}
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, is this reduce/merge operation computationally expensive?

Comment: Define “expensive.” This word makes any sense in CS only when used in comparison to smth else.